# Leaf turning yellow on newly bought Chinese Evergreen (Aglaonema). What could it be?

Tags: indoors

Some more info:
Bought it and could see that the soil was dry the next day. Watered it thoroughly with 6.5 PH tap water. 
Plant has a couple of leaves turning yellow, one of them is almost completely yellow by now.
[image]

I can see the roots kind of sticking out the pot. I am planning in repotting it in a week or so. Can this be the problem?

Comment: can you add another picture as this does not look like an aglaonema